# Cant run a migration when deploying. Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, deployment, laravel-5, laravel-envoy

Consider the following task for envoy:

```
@task('deploy', ['on' => 'web'])
    cd personal_site
    php artisan down
    git pull origin master
    composer install
    php artisan migrate
    php artisan up
@endtask

php artisan migrate // Blows up
```

The error is:

```
[user@xxxx]: **************************************
*     Application In Production!     *
**************************************
[user@xxxx]: Command Cancelled!
[user@xxxx]: Application is now live.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This warning is a security measure to prevent accidental migrations being run on production environment. If you're sure you want to run them in that environment, you need to use **--force** option:

```
php artisan migrate --force
```